# Importing text files to Excel - lines from each file are placed in separate columns on same row

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code on this site but I haven't been able to adjust it for my own needs though I think it must be a very quick fix.

The code imports a series of text files to excel. A file is opened and the first line of this file is placed in A1, the second line in A2 and so on. When a new file is opened, the text is placed in the next available cell in column A (all files are read into column A).

I want to make a slight modification. I want the first line of file 1 in A1, the second line in B1 and so on (i.e. all the lines from File 1 are kept in Row 1). Then, the lines in File 2 are placed in Row 2, File 3 in Row 3 etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim Items() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range

    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("D:\YourDirectory\")  

    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files
        ' Open the file
        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

        ' Read the file one line at a time
        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

            ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
            Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

            ' Put data on one row in active sheet
            For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
                cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
            Next

            ' Move to next row
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop

        ' Clean up
        FileText.Close
    Next file

    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap. Pretty easy. Just needed to adjust how your columns and rows are being offset and to not have it delimit each line as it's read.

See the adjusted code below:

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder, file As file, FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String, Items() As String
Dim i As Long, cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("D:\YourDirectory\")

Dim x As Long
x = 1 'to offset rows for each file

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files

    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1)

    ' Open the file
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    Dim i As Long
    i = 0 'to offset columsn for each line
    ' Read the file one line at a time
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream

        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine 'read line

        cl.Offset(, i).Value = TextLine 'fill cell

        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    FileText.Close

    x = x + 1

Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottHoltzman, this is exactly what I asked for above. When I ran the code however I realised that I had forgotton about one important thing with respect to my text files. There is often a number of different 'sections' in each file. I would like each section to be a given a separate row in my excel file. At the start of each file there are 3 or 4 lines of introductory text, then each section begins with a line containing the word "FINEX". How would you modify your code to start a new row in excel when it encounters a line with the word FINEX? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd think replacing all the references to rows and columns with each other would be sufficient.  Try:

1. Replace `cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)` with `cl.Offset(i, 0).Value = Items(i)`
2. Replace `Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)` with `Set cl = cl.Offset(0, 1)`

Does that do the trick?

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't quite do it I'm afraid, it writes everything to the first row. It is closer than I got though. I made the change in (1) alright but hadn't modified the 'set cl' line